# How to implement Master Pages in HTML5

Tags: html

I am working on an HTML5 project in which I would like to implement a Master Page, the way we have in .Net.
However, this application will not have any .Net code.
Appreciate your help in guiding me towards this.

Comment: Do you wish to manage large contents?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use static site generators for this kind of work.  On my [blog](http://jbeckwith.com), I use jekyll:

http://jekyllrb.com/

It does require ruby, so that can be a bit of a thing.  The good news is that it's relatively easy to set up.  If you want to stick with .NET stuff, there's a static site generator that does basically the same thing:

https://github.com/Code52/pretzel

Happy Coding!